# Calling controller method from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I need to call a method of controller named `test()` from a Javascript. Script code is given below:

```
function changeColor(id, color) 
{
    element = document.getElementById(id);
    qnid = document.form1.pickupFrom.qnid;

    //window.location =  "<?= site_url('controller/test') ?>"
}
```

Is it possible? And how to pass the parameters?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Is it your intention that the current page will be replaced by whatever that request returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what parameters youn need to pass. Are they PHP parameters? The you're doing just fine, or better see @Sudhir answer.

If your params come from javascript you shoulnd't use the `site_url()` function (since when it elaborates and spit out the url, javascript is yet to be executed). It would be much easier to build a URL this way:

```
function changeColor(id, color) {
            element = document.getElementById(id);
            qnid = document.form1.pickupFrom.qnid;

            window.location =  "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/controller/test/"+element+"/"+qnid;
}
```

I'm assuming those two are the parameters you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it as:

```
window.location.href =  "<?php echo site_url('yourcontroller_name/function_name/param1/param2') ?>"
```

Hope it helps