# Calling a method in the controller using jquery / making a template work

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I got a copy of a template with a simple HTML design from a friend that he purchased online and I'm trying to create something from it but I can't seem to get a part of it to work. The template has a sample registration page which is good because there is a validation function that checks if all the required fields are filled up. I was thinking that maybe I could add my codes to the onFinished function (in validation.js) to call a method in the controller (Main.php) to insert the entered data to the database then change to another view. But I'm stumped in making it work.

So far, I've tried the answers provided in other threads and tutorials but I can't get them to work. I don't know if they're for CI2 and I'm using CI3.

The following are just the bare essentials since the template has thousands of lines (especially the one for the view). I'm using CodeIgniter for this project.

`Main.php`

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('model','',TRUE);
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->view('_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('_menu');
    $this->load->view('view_mainpage');
}
```

`view_mainpage.php`

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" action="" id="validate">
    <div><label>Name</label>
    <div><input type="text" name="name"></div></div>
</form>
```

`validation.js`

```
$(function () {
    $("#wizard-validate").steps({
        headerTag: ".wizard-title",
        bodyTag: ".wizard-container",
        transitionEffect: "fade",
        onFinished: function () {
            // yayyy! all validation is pass.. now we can send data to server
            // or display message ;)
            // alert("submitted!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try use Ajax to submit the data

Comment: was the jquery library loaded?

Comment: I assume the jquery library was loaded since an alert box is displayed when I click the finish button (although I commented out the alert on the codes above)

Comment: I tried the suggestions given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118332/calling-controller-method-from-javascript however neither window.location = "<?php echo site_url('control_main/sample'); ?>"; or window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('control_main/sample') ?>" works when I add them on the onFinished function. The url becomes http://localhost/cto/index.php/control_main/<?=%20site_url(%27control_main/sample%27)%20?>. I'm trying to start start from calling a method from javascript then work up to insert data to the database.

Comment: Using window.location.href =  "sample"; instead of window.location = "<?php echo site_url('control_main/sample'); ?>"; or window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('control_main/sample') ?>" works. I'm not able to call a method from the controller. However, is it secure?